# Correct way to set PERMANENT environment variables from script

Tags: shell, scripting, environment-variables

I want to do a very simple install process for my app framework.  I've got everything working, but I want to set two environment variables.  I want to update the `PATH` and also set a `HOME` variable.

I know I can't set a var on the parent process, so how can I do this?  I don't want to require the user to execute `source foo`, I want them to be able to just run `foo install` and the deed is done.

Surely, there is SOME way?

EDIT: Sorry - I don't mean the actual `HOME`, I mean a `MY_FRAMEWORK_HOME` variable!

Comment: . Somefile or source somefile are the normal ways. If you can give them a function, that's another way.

Comment: HOME=/my/home PATH=/my/path my.install

Comment: Or suggest lines to them that they can edit into their shell profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$HOME` variable isn't something you should mess with, generally; it's user-dependent.  You don't want the user to suddenly have a different home directory!  (And if you do, you should edit his home directory that is set in `/etc/passwd`—which of course requires `root` permissions.)

The `$PATH` is another matter and should be set in his `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.  There are various arguments as to which you should use, which I won't get into here.

Let's say you want to append `/var/myapp/bin` to the user's path.  You can do this by adding the line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/var/myapp/bin"
```

to the user's `~/.bashrc`.  A good method of doing this while avoiding adding the line if it's already there is discussed [on the `vi` stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676):

```
ex -sc '$a
export PATH="$PATH:/var/myapp/bin"
.
$-,$!uniq
x' ~/.bashrc
```

Be warned that if you are adding more than one line this way, the same safety check to avoid adding them if they are already there won't work.  You'll need different logic for that.

---

You might also consider a different course of action: Add symlinks to your command binaries into `/usr/local/bin`, which is typically already included in the `$PATH`.

So let's say, as in my example above, that you want to add `/var/myapp/bin` to the user's PATH.  The reason you might want to do this in the first place is because you have some commands (shell scripts or binaries, doesn't matter) in `/var/myapp/bin` that you want the user to be able to execute from the command line.  Let's say these commands are `myapp_command` and `myapp_othercommand`.

You could make these available in the PATH by creating symlinks like so:

```
ln -s /var/myapp/bin/myapp_command /usr/local/bin/myapp_command
ln -s /var/myapp/bin/myapp_othercommand /usr/local/bin/myapp_othercommand
```

The first argument to `ln -s` is the TARGET, the second argument is the LINK name you want to create to point to the target.  (For more, see `man ln`.)

Comment: Excellent!  As a side note, I'm not messing with the actual `HOME` var, I want `MY_HOME`.  Can you describe a bit more how adding the symlinks from a shell script would look?

Comment: @mtyson, I added some more details.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Just **export** variables:

```
export NAME1="value1"
export NAME2="value2"
./my.install
```

Edit:
Doing this is possible from following shells (I know):

- DASH
- BASH
- KSH
- ZSH

Edit 2:
Move `my.install` to `my.install.real`, and create a new file called `my.install`:

```
export HOME='SAMPLE VALUE'
export PATH='SAMPLE VALUE'
./my.install.real
unset HOME
unset PATH
```

Comment: From the question you are answering: *"I know I can't set a var on the parent process, so how can I do this?"*  The point is to set a *permanent* environment variable.  For that you need to edit the profile.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does not check for specific lines already present on the `PATH`.